# Retrieve YML / YAML properties

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a external yaml properties files that I have loaded and I want to retrieve. But the suggested way to get YAML is like so:

```java
@Value("${some.var}");
```

and this isn't working.

I am loading the files in like so:

```java
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {       
    String userHome = System.getProperty('user.home');
    ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    "${userHome}/.boot/beapi_server.yml",
                    "${userHome}/.boot/beapi.yml",
                    "${userHome}/.boot/beapi_db.yml",
                    "${userHome}/.boot/beapi_api.yml"
            )
    );
    Collections.reverse(locations);
    
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    for (String location : locations) {
        String finalLocation = location.toString();
    
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new FileSystemResource(finalLocation));
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(Objects.requireNonNull(yaml.getObject()));
    }
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

The actuator/configprops also don't show the properties.

What am I doing wrong? A bit frustrated.

Comment: Where have you placed that annotation? Is the class it is in a Spring Bean?

Comment: well I tried in in the MVCConfig class (marked as @Configuration) and also in Application class. Neither will show properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out and wanted to post the answer for others to see.

After loading the external files into your PropertySources, you can now access them through **@ConfigurationProperties** annotation by referencing the YML structure prefix head and then just access the properties directly through assignment

```
// 'tomcat' if the top level prefix in my yml file
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="tomcat")
class something{

    ArrayList jvmArgs

}
```

Now lets look at my yml:

```
tomcat:
    jvmArgs:
        -'-Xms1536m'
        -'-Xmx2048m'
        -'-XX:PermSize=256m'
        -'-XX:MaxPermSize=512m'
        -'-XX:MaxNewSize=256m'
        -'-XX:NewSize=256m',
        -'-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'
        -'-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC'
        -'-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode'
        -'-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing'
        -'-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10'
        -'-XX:+UseParNewGC'
        -'-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200'
        -'-XX:MaxGCMinorPauseMillis=50'
        -'-XX:SurvivorRatio=128'
        -'-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0'
        -'-server'
        -'-noverify'
        -'-Xshare:off'
        -'-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
        -'-XX:+EliminateLocks'
        -'-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent'
        -'-XX:+UseBiasedLocking'
        -'-XX:+UseTLAB'
```

And we see this will directly assign the value jvmArgs to the ArrayList JvmArgs in the class above. Simple.

So, rather simple and elegant solution once you know how... but knowing how is the trick isn't it :)

Answer (score -2):

i'm using yaml configuration too. in my case, you have to create a configuration class then you can autowired it.

this is my code:

PdfConfig.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pdf")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class PdfConfig {

    private String licensePath;
    private Watermark watermark;

    // setter getter goes here

}
```

PdfServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PdfServiceImpl implements PdfService {

    @Autowired
    private PdfConfig pdfConfig;
}
```

application-local.yml

```
#### Pdf Config ####
pdf:
  license-path: classpath:license/development/itextkey.xml
  watermark:
    image-path: classpath:static/img/logo.png
    opacity: 0.2f
    enabled: true
```

If you want to learn about setting spring yaml, you can go to this link [spring-yaml](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml)

Hope this helped!

Comment: There’s quite a bit missing here - for example the configuration of your bean as `@ConfigurationProperties`. Also, the OP is loading custom additional YAML whereas your (incomplete) example is focused on `application.yaml`.

Comment: ahh my bad. forgot to include the annotation. i'll edit my code. thanks mate @BoristheSpider